# Calling javascript modal inside another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to integrate the modal i.e(javascript function given by janrain) inside the modal which is already existing. my site is running in MVC architechture.  There are many tabs in my screen, and  I am writing all the javascript function for all the tabs in the **tabs.htm** file.

Once A tab is clicked, it is calling javascript function in tabs.htm file then ajax request to the specific html file, then displaying all the contents of html in the clicked tab.

Say in A tab i am having one button and on onclick event i am calling the javascript function in tabs.htm file then calling the modal from specific tabs html file and then displaying the modal in the tab.

Now i need to add the modal given by janrain shown below, Below the other modal which is also below.

```
(function() {
    if (typeof window.janrain !== 'object') window.janrain = {};
    if (typeof window.janrain.settings !== 'object') window.janrain.settings = {};

    janrain.settings.tokenUrl = 'MY_URL';

    function isReady() { janrain.ready = true; };
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", isReady, false);
    } else {
      window.attachEvent('onload', isReady);
    }

    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.id = 'janrainAuthWidget';

    if (document.location.protocol === 'https:') {
      e.src = 'https://rpxnow.com/js/lib/oauth/engage.js';
    } else {
      e.src = 'http://widget-cdn.rpxnow.com/js/lib/oauth/engage.js';
    }

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
})();
```

This is the modal i am already calling in the button click event in A's htm file.

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">
<table width="100px" cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td width="140px">
Name     
</td>     
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" class="glow" style="width:150px;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="140px">
E-Mail ID
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="txtEmailQuest" name="txtEmailQuest" class="glow" style="width:150px;">
</td>
</tr>                 
</table>
<div style="text-align:center">
<input id="ask" type="image" src="/templates/default/images/askQuestion.jpg"  onClick="ValidateFormHere()"/>
</div>
```

Now i want to add the javascript modal to this form.  If i kept the javascript modal in the tabs.htm file how can i call that when this modal is called.  If i paste the javascript file in the modal pasted above, it is not working.  Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Vignesh. You'll want to do two things:

1 - Go to https://rpxnow.com/relying_parties/your_rp_here and go to Deployment > Sign In For Web. Set your widget type as embedded (NOT modal), then hit Save and Publish.

2 - In your form where you want the buttons to show up, add this line of code:

```
<div id="janrainEngageEmbed"></div>
```

There's a possibility that your JavaScript that causes that tab to load won't actually load the widget. If that happens, call the janrain.engage.signin.widget.init() function in the same event that loads that tab. It should get the widget to load for you.